# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://cs.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Relationship between Undecidable Problems and Recursively Enumerable languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12747/relationship-between-undecidable-problems-and-recursively-enumerable-languages)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Why don't we emphasize "length of input string" when considering time complexity of sorting algorithms?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/why-dont-we-emphasize-length-of-input-string-when-considering-time-complexity)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Find out the largest LCM of the partitions of n](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13101/find-out-the-largest-lcm-of-the-partitions-of-n)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 7)
- [Show that only a few multiples of .01 decimal are powers of 2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12952/show-that-only-a-few-multiples-of-01-decimal-are-powers-of-2)

  **Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [Is it decidable if a language described by number of occurences is regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12718/is-it-decidable-if-a-language-described-by-number-of-occurences-is-regular)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Why is software emulation of alternative architectures so hard/slow?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13100/why-is-software-emulation-of-alternative-architectures-so-hard-slow)

  **Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 7)
- [Howto formally go about proving that two LTL formulas are equivalent?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13092/howto-formally-go-about-proving-that-two-ltl-formulas-are-equivalent)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Multicommodity circulation formulation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12963/multicommodity-circulation-formulation)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Inductive vs. recursive definition](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13225/inductive-vs-recursive-definition)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [Classification of job shop scheduling problems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13219/classification-of-job-shop-scheduling-problems)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

Answer (score 5):

#### Internal eval:

This site stays as a personal reminder to me of how I suck at gauging the potential of site proposals. It's doing REALLY WELL.

I particularly love how engaged and self-critical the community is here - quality appears to stay reasonably high even in the face of WAVES of students asking homework questions, lazy questions and bogus answers criticized and down-voted.

It isn't *quite* ready to graduate, but realistically the only thing holding it back is that the distribution of folks at various upper rep-levels hasn't quite caught up yet (the start of the school year this fall has produced a huge increase in activity) - I fully expect this to resolve itself in the next few months.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. Quite a couple of users have stepped up over the last few months and "policed" the site; I find myself acting as mediator more and more.